# C# Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, file, csv, export

```
namespace Tema2_PS.Services
{
public class CSVExporter : Exporter
{
   public FileContentResult convert(List<Ticket> ticketList)
   {
       string csv = "";

        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv.ToString()), "text/csv", "Export.csv");
   }
}
}
```

Comment: you surely mean `return new File(...)`.. But even then `File` is surely not convertible to `FileContentResult`. However we don´t know how those two classes rely on each other and thus how to do this conversion.

Comment: `File` is a method inside the `Controller`. Your code isn't in a controller, thus it doesn't compile. As such, you will want to `new` up a `FileContentResult`.

Comment: You want controller file object but you are getting System.io.File() Try using  this.File()

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to return the class File instead of an instance.
Without knowing the contents of your FileContentResult class i can only assume it takes the file as a parameter in the constructor.

```
return new FileContentResult(new File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv.ToString()), "text/csv", "Export.csv"));
```

if that is not the case and FileContentresult inherits from the File class

```
return new File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv.ToString()), "text/csv", "Export.csv"))
```

Comment: I use MVC, and I have this method in TicketController:                
public FileContentResult Export(String type, int movieId)
        {
            Exporter exporter = ExportFactory.get(type);

            List<Ticket> ticketList = TicketDAO.getInstance().getTickets(movieId);

            return exporter.convert(ticketList);
        }

Comment: did you get a solution to this problem ?